# Screen used to fade to black and allowed for automatic wake up by touching mousepad; now it just suspends (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, and if I wasn't using it, the display would after a while slowly dim to black. If I touched the mouse pad, the display would immediately come back on. Now, for some reason instead of doing that, it immediately suspends, so I have to use the power button to turn it back on. I have tried altering the Power Settings to no avail. When I check the Display Settings it says "Could not get screen information". I'm not sure what else to do to get it back to the way it was, so any help would be greatly appreciated!